# Ubuntu Keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, 18.04

I've been looking on the internet to figure out what's my problem, but unfortunatly  I don't find.

I install the new version of ubuntu 18.04, everything was good, then I reboot, and *magic* my keyboard is no longer working.
The keyboard work on the GRUB, work on my dual boot windows, but no longer on my ubuntu.

I've tryied to do `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` but nothing change after the reboot :/

Thx

EDIT: external keyboard are working good on my ubuntu and that's weird